# How to get current page ID outside the loop?

Tags: pages, id

How to get current page ID outside the loop?

Comment: Strange, how are you using the code, what have you tried. What errors are you getting. As it stands, it is difficult to help you and all answers is a shot in the dark. Please file an [edit]

Comment: `<?php global $post; 
$thePostID=$post->ID;?>
<?php elseif($thePostID==35) : ?>`

Comment: Please file an [edit] with all the extra code/info. Don't use the comment section for stuff that should be in your question :-)

Comment: Your post has been automatically flagged as low quality, please comply to my requests above :-)

Comment: i m not getting any errors, actually i want to display google map on my page, so map is't displaying...

Comment: in header.php i am using if else to showing according to page ids

Comment: As I said, all of that info should go into your question, not in the comments section. Please [edit] your question

Comment: Dear @Programmer, please read [ask]. You received automatic flags about the quality of your post. You got suggestions how to fix that. Please try to get over that so your question can stay open and you don't receive down votes. Thank you.

Comment: You've accepted an answer already but the correct answer (arguably a duplicate question) is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109468/21376

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Try**

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

**or** (I don't know the difference)

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->post->ID;
```

Comment: i have tried all the stuff found on google but nothing happened

Comment: it's hard to know what "all the stuff you found" is :) make sure the code is in a function, that you call that function and start debuging with echoing something else before which has to be visible...

Comment: i did't getting id using function, and the "stuff" is
`global $wp_query;
$thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
`

`global $post;
$thePostID = $post->ID;
`

`global $wp_query;
$page = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$page_id = $page->ID;
`

`$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
`

Comment: first one was correct...

Comment: These solutions will give you page ID only if used  before the Loop starts. Once the Loop starts, `$post` will be set to each post in the Loop in turn.

Answer (score 86):

You can simply do,

```
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer...

Comment: Agreed. This should be the answer.

Comment: Definately it should be the right answer. I'm trying to get the current id of a post or a page, and this is the only way it gives me the right Id without having to hardcode conditions.

Comment: Brilliant, right answer for me

Comment: Thank you. Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who this still isn't working for, you will need to use some sort of add_action (you can choose which one you want to use). For my example, this will return the current page ID without any problems, regardless of whether in a plugin folder, functions php, or elsewhere.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'showid');

function showid(){
    global $wp_query;
    $theid = intval($wp_query->queried_object->ID);
    echo $theid;
}
```

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Outside the loop:

```
$current_page = get_page_by_path($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            
if(isset($current_page->ID)) {
    $current_page_id = $current_page->ID;
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, but I think the other approaches are simpler. And I'm nervous this might make a database request.

Comment: This will not work when creating a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Outside the loop :

```
  //remember to call wp_reset_postdata(); after while loop
  // otherwise you will get wrong id.
   global $post;
   $post_id =  $post->ID;
```

Inside the loop:

```
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $post_id = the_ID();
}
```