# How can I use get_permalink() outside the loop?

Tags: loop

I've been struggling with this question for a while and although there's some information regarding this subject I'm not sure how to implement it. My question regards sharing the current page.

I am using `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >var bShareOpt = {url: "<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"};</script>` which shows the permalink of the last page instead of the current page. If I add the post_id number `<?php echo get_permalink(2926); ?>` it shows the correct post.

This is happening because it's being called outside the loop.

Using `get_queried_object_id` or `get_queried_object` is apparently another option to do so.

But unfortunately my PHP knowledge is very limited in order to glue the pieces together. I appreciate any help!

I like to add:
Permalink settings are: website.com/%postname%.html

Each social icon on the homepage should share that specific post. I did the the same on the English version of that website with Facebook Likes which works like a charm. Now i'm trying to achieve the same with the Chinese social icons...

At [loop.php](https://github.com/jiangzhouq/smart-mag/blob/master/loop.php) on line 30 I call the get_permalink() function as such:

```
<?php if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='zh-hans' ) : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >
        var bShareOpt = {url: "<?php echo get_permalink( $postid ); ?>"};
    </script>
    <div class="social-content">
        <div class="bshare-custom">
            <div class="bsPromo bsPromo2"></div>
            <a title="分享到微信" class="bshare-weixin" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
            <a title="分享到新浪微博" class="bshare-sinaminiblog" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
            <a title="分享到QQ空间" class="bshare-qzone"></a>
            <a title="更多平台" class="bshare-more bshare-more-icon more-style-addthis"></a>
            <span class="BSHARE_COUNT bshare-share-count" style="float: none;">19.5K</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of your code?

Comment: Included. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Why is this occurring outside the loop?  Why not just do it inside?

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress Development community, @Sp0cK! I am still somewhat confused as to your desired outcome, and I must second @m0r7if3r's question: the posted code segment displays post-relevant data which is the very reason that The Loop exists - why do it externally? You mention that the posted code segment is in your theme's `loop.php` file, however the `loop.php` file in the linked GitHub repository does not contain the segment. Additionally, within the repository, the referenced line #28 appears to be _inside_ The Loop. Where are you trying to use the posted code segment?

Comment: If you say Line #28 is inside the loop. Then I'm confused why it doesn't return the correct $post_id. I'm trying to use the posted code segment in every article on the homepage. See [image](http://www.seomandarin.com/wp-content/uploads/article-share2.jpg) the social icons appear with mouse hover

Comment: @m0r7if3r Basically because I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: I can't find `get_permalink()` in `loop.php` on either branch of the linked repo.  Are you trying to insert this at line 28 (between `div.column.half` and `article`?

Comment: @m0r7if3r That's right. In my own loop.php it's on line 30 actually to be exact. The line after the `<article <?php post_class('highlights'); ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">` Would this be in or outside the loop? Cheers!

Comment: That's inside the loop.  I think you've mis-diagnosed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) outside of the loop, you need to define the post $id parameter.

You can [access the post ID outside of the loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161711/how-to-get-current-page-id-outside-the-loop) by invoking the global $post object and then referencing it's ID value.

So your code would now look like this:

```
<?php if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='zh-hans' ) : 

    global $post;
    $postid = $post->ID;

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >
        var bShareOpt = {url: "<?php echo get_permalink( $postid ); ?>"};
    </script>
    <div class="social-content">
        <div class="bshare-custom">
            <div class="bsPromo bsPromo2"></div>
            <a title="分享到微信" class="bshare-weixin" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
            <a title="分享到新浪微博" class="bshare-sinaminiblog" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
            <a title="分享到QQ空间" class="bshare-qzone"></a>
            <a title="更多平台" class="bshare-more bshare-more-icon more-style-addthis"></a>
            <span class="BSHARE_COUNT bshare-share-count" style="float: none;">19.5K</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It returns the last $postid - meaning it might still not be in the loop

Comment: Hey Sp0ck, in order for me to better help you I need to see the whole code. The link you posted to github doesn't include the code you shared here...

Answer (score 0):

The unique way I sort this out has been using PHP (not wordpress functions):

```
<?php if($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] == "/my-url/"){ ?>
   Do something if the user is in the "my-url" page
<?php } ?>
```